# Getting module not found in node js also trie reinstall node but not working

Tags: node.js

i am Getting module not found error while i am trying to run the node application i have tried deleting and installing all modules packages and also reinstalled nodejs but nothing works please some help regarding this.

```
Error: Cannot find module 'server'
Require stack:
- D:\video call\server.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:889:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:745:27)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:961:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:92:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\video call\server.js:3:16)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1072:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1101:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:937:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:76:12) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [ 'D:\\video call\\server.js' ]
}
```

node version 14.17.6
and `server.js` file is in root directory

Comment: it's `--version` not `version`. try `--version`.

Comment: @AminTaghikhani sorry first time I sent wrong error please check now.

Comment: can you add your command?

Comment: @AminTaghikhani it's node server.js

Comment: can you create a new file and just put `console.log('hi')` in file and check work or not?

Comment: @AminTaghikhani yeah it's working

Comment: `node` cannot find your `server.js` file, are you run `node server.js` in `server.js` directory? your file name is correct?

Comment: Do you have any `require` lines in your file?